# Get selected day and current day value of Framework 7 Calendar

Tags: jquery, html-framework-7

**Hi, I would like to get the value of selected day, and current day in the framework 7 calendar component**

```
var calendar = app.calendar.create({
containerEl: '#test-calendar',
monthNames : monthNames,
dayNamesShort: dayNames,
firstDay: 0,
weekHeader: true,
events: [
    {
      id: 1, //example
      title: 'my event',
      from: new Date(year, month, day),
      to: new Date(year, month, 14),
    },
    {
      id: 2, //example
      title: 'my event',
      from: new Date(year, month, day),
      to: new Date(year, month, 14),
    }
],
toolbar: false,
on: {
  init: function(c) {
    $$('.calendar-month-name').text(monthNames[c.currentMonth] +' ' + c.currentYear);
  },
  monthYearChangeStart: function (c) {
    $$('.calendar-month-name').text(monthNames[c.currentMonth] +' ' + c.currentYear);
  },
}
```

});

for example:

> var currentday = calendar.getCurrentDay();
>
> var selectedday = calendar.getSelectedDay();
>
> is there a method or property to get this on framework 7?

Answer (score 0):

i found out the answer, but for the current day of the month i just use the selector to get it, its the same anyways..

```
on: {
  init: function(calendar) {
    $$('.calendar-month-name').text(monthNames[calendar.currentMonth] +' ' + calendar.currentYear);
  },
  monthYearChangeStart: function (calendar) {
    $$('.calendar-month-name').text(monthNames[calendar.currentMonth] +' ' + calendar.currentYear);
  },
  dayClick: function(calendar, dayEl, year, month, day) {
    var selectedDay = day; // selected day
    var currentDay = $$('.calendar-day-today span').text(); //current day
    console.log(currentDay);
  }
}
```